# Protecting namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

This are my namespaces and classes in them.

```
MyProject
    ManagerClass
    ProjectClass
    UiClass


MyProject.Audio
    MusicManager
MyProject.Audio.DynamicMusic
    DynamicMusicSong
    DynamicMusicTrack
    DynamicMusicClip
```

Is there someway I can make the namespaces under Audio only accessible to classes in Audio? I want them to be invisible for classes in `MyProject`, except the ones in the actual Audio namespace.

Comment: Why don't you just have separate contracts (`interface`s) and implementation assemblies (irrespective of namespaces); make all the `interface`s of interest to callers `public` in one assembly, and make **all** concrete classes `internal` in the other assembly.  That way no one sees the implementaton; is de-coupled; and you have fine control over who sees what

Comment: @MickyD thats a great idea. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem good sir

Answer (score 0):

For classes there are the access modifiers `public` and `internal` ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers#class-and-struct-accessibility))

> *public:*
>   The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.
>
> *internal:* 
>   The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly, but not from another assembly.

A more fine-grained control is not possible*, hence you cannot declare visibility on a per-namepace level.

*This is not 100% percent true. There is a possibility to allow other assemblies to access `internal` types and methods, the [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8). Anyway, I'd advise you to use it with utter care, since you increase coupling between those assemblies. They will rely on the internals of each other, which will increase the likelyhood of an unstable codebase (more changes). I'm using the attributes solely for testing purposes.